# Xamarin forms convert image uri address to real image

Tags: c#, sqlite, binding, uri, xamarin.forms

I am trying to solve uri address converting to image issue. Main idea , what I am doing I want to pick image from a gallery, bind it and save it to database. Everything is working, I can save string image path to class property, but unfortunately I can't convert that address to my imageSource where I will displaying my image, because now I see empty image circle.

This is where I am selecting image from gallery and trying to convert into image:

```
IGalleryImageService galleryService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IGalleryImageService>();
            galleryService.ImageSelected += (o, imageSourceEventArgs) =>
            {      
                Uri uri = new Uri(imageSourceEventArgs.ImageSource);
                (ActivePage.Page as PageTemplate).CarImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(uri.ToString());
                ActivePage.CarImageBindable = (ActivePage.Page as PageTemplate).CarImage.Source.GetValue(StreamImageSource.StreamProperty).ToString(); // here I am trying to convert from path address to image
            };
            galleryService.SelectImage();
```

Here is my PageTemplate

```
    public partial class PageTemplate: ContentPage
    {
public CircleImage CarImage
        {
            get
            {
                return Car;
            }
            set
            {
                Car = value;
            }
        }
}
```

and PageTemplate.xaml where I am displaying images.

```
<controls:CircleImage x:Name="Car" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Aspect="AspectFill">
</controls:CircleImage>
```

This is my bindable property from Unit2 class:

```
public string CarImageBindable
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CarImage;
            }
            set
            {
                base.CarImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CarImageBindable));
            }
        }
```

And another property from Core project Unit class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public string CarImage { get; set; }
```

That's why I decided to make all properties as string data type, because I want to save image path. And yes, then convert again from database to physical image.

Thank you for answers or suggestions.

Comment: Hello, in your code there is a line 
 (ActivePage.Page as PageTemplate).CarImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(uri.ToString());

why not just 
 (ActivePage.Page as PageTemplate).CarImage.Source = uri;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved issue like this:

```
IGalleryImageService galleryService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IGalleryImageService>();
            galleryService.ImageSelected += (o, imageSourceEventArgs) =>
            {      
                ActiveParking.CarImageBindable = imageSourceEventArgs.ImageSource.ToString();
                (ActiveParking.Page as PageTemplate).CarImage.Source = galleryService.GetImage(imageSourceEventArgs.ImageSource.ToString());

            };
            galleryService.SelectImage();
```